# The text does not appear after I click the button

Tags: c#

I am following a tutorial but I am not receiving the same results. Based off the code below, a button is supposed to appear. After clicking on that button, a small dialogue box appears with the message "hello". The results I am receiving is after running my code the button appears but when I click on it, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.ComponentModel;
     using System.Data;
     using System.Drawing;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Windows.Forms;

           namespace NewPrjct
           {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
               public Form1()
               {
                 InitializeComponent();
               }

               private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Hello", "MyTitle");
               }

             }
           }
```

Comment: Chances are your button1_Click event handler is not infact wired up to the button1_Click event. Win forms code behind I imagine would tell you

Comment: It would help if you showed us the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form1.designer.cs there should be an initializer for the button to link it to the form window. It is quite possible that it is not related to the form1.

This generally happens if you copy and paste a button or don't click on the button to open the source...

Go to to Form Design window and double click on the button and type the Messagebox.show("Hello", "My Title"); in there, it will either open up in

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Hello", "MyTitle");
           }
```

and initialize your button or in some cases it will rename button 1 to

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Hello", "MyTitle");
               }
```

Answer (score -1):

Did generate this code by double clicking the button in Visual Studio or Type this out manually? If you typed it out manually you need to add code elsewhere I believe. I think you can just double click the button in the designer and it will add what you need.

Comment: Open the Form1.Designer.cs file and look for the button1 code under InitializeComponent() make sure you see the line 
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

Then outside of InitializeComponent() ensure you see 
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;